# Continuity at $x$ of increasing function if certain sequences exist

Tags: measure-theory, continuity

I'm working through the first few chapters of Royden-Fitzpatrick to learn measure theory and I got stuck on this question.

Let $f$ be increasing on $I$, an open interval. Then for $x \in I$, $f$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if there exist sequences $\{r_n\}$ and $\{s_n\}$ in $I$ such that  $r_n < x < s_n$ for all $n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}[f(s_n)-f(r_n)]=0.$

I know $f$ is continuous at $x$ if for each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that if $|x-y|<\delta$ for $y\in I$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$, but I'm getting stuck. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One direction is quite easy. Assume continuity at $x$. Then use $r_n=x-\frac{1}{n}$ and $s_n=x+\frac{1}{n}$. Since $r_n,s_n \to x$ as $n \to \infty$ and $f$ is continuous at $x$, we get $f(r_n)$ and $f(s_n) \to f(x)$ as $n \to \infty$. Thus $|f(r_n)-f(s_n)|\to |f(x)-f(x)|=0$ as $n \to \infty$.

The other direction takes a bit more work. Now assume we have such sequences. Let $\epsilon>0$. There is some $N>0$ such that $|f(r_n)-f(s_n)|<\epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$. Take $\delta = \min \{ |r_N-x|, |s_N-x| \}$ (notice that $\delta>0$ since $x\not= r_N,s_N$ because $r_N < x < s_N$).

Consider $0<|x-y|<\delta$. Then $r_N \leq x-\delta<y<x+\delta \leq s_N$. Thus $f(r_N)<f(y)<f(s_N)$ (here we finally use the assumption that $f$ is increasing). Notice that $f(r_N)<f(x)<f(s_N)$ as well (since $r_N<x<s_N$). Now remember that $|f(r_N)-f(s_N)|<\epsilon$, so $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq |f(r_N)-f(s_N)| < \epsilon$. Thus $f$ is continuous as $x$.